# Using 何 with the general counter ~つ

Tags: grammar, counters

Is there a way to use 何 with the general counter ~つ to ask "how many..." in the same vein as in sentences like  "何歳ですか。" or "本は何冊買いましたか。"?

If not, how do you ask something like "How many ideas do you have", where (I think) one would normally use the generic counter? Do you have to resort to 何個?

Comment: Related:  [What's the difference between 何 and 幾 when referring to amounts?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12639/78)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to use 何 with the general counter ~つ to ask "how many..."

No, we don't say 何つ. We say いくつ (幾つ).

> If not, how do you ask something like "How many ideas do you have", where (I think) one would normally use the generic counter?

You could use いくつ, as in 「アイデアはいくつありますか。」「いくつアイデアが浮かびましたか。」 etc...

Comment: So you can't say "いくつ**の**アイデア"?

Comment: It's not a noun, it's an adverb. It doesn't need の. You could say いくつかの or いくつもの though of course they mean different things.

Comment: `It's not a noun, it's an adverb.` <-- ん？　明鏡国語辞典 categorizes いくつ as a 名詞... noting 副詞的にも使う. @Fire

Comment: @Hans 「いくつ**の**アイデア」「みっつ**の**りんご」「何本**の**ペン」「３本**の**ペン」「何匹**の**犬」「２匹**の**犬」 etc are all grammatically correct. It's correct to say 「いくつ**の**アイデアがありますか」「３つ**の**アイデアが出ました」「何匹**の**犬を飼っていますか」「ここに３本**の**鉛筆があります」 etc. It's more common/natural, at least in daily conversation, to say them as 「XXはいくつありますか」「XXが３つあります/３つXXがあります」「犬は何匹飼っていますか/何匹犬を飼っていますか」「ここにペンが３本あります」etc., using いくつ / n+counter adverbially.